# jQuery accordion bug

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

On page-load accordion should be collapsed...but here on page-load it's expanded and I don't know how to fix this bug?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
    $('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

    //Set The Accordion Content Width
    var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
    $('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });

    //Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
    $('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
    $('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');

    // The Accordion Effect
    $('.accordion-header').click(function () {
        if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
            $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        }

        else {
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        }
    });

    return false;
});​
```

#### Here is [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YsY7n/) of my code.

Comment: You should read 'your' code comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following part of the code from your example and it will work just the way you expect:

```
//Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');
```

#### [jsFiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Uf7Nj/)

Answer (score -3):

for me just adding display: none to the accordion-content div seemed to do the trick:

```
$('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth }).css('display':'none');
```

Here's a demo of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/YsY7n/1/